# How to find all Stored Procedures that referring particular Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I want to find all the list of stored procedures which is referring a given stored procedure. I am using SSMS 2017. Can anyone suggest a query for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following query, in the `WHERE` clause, instead of `'%YourProcedureName%'`, you can replace your procedure name, it will return the other procedures which has the given procedure name in it.

```
-- Find specific word in the SPs
SELECT DISTINCT P.[name], M.[definition]
FROM sys.procedures P
JOIN sys.sql_modules M ON M.[object_id] = P.[object_id]
WHERE M.[definition] LIKE '%YourProcedureName%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%TableNameOrWhatever%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this [solution](https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/2018/12/sql-server-find-created-and-modified-stored-procedure-with-date-and-time.html). For More information, you should visit this [link](https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/2018/12/sql-server-find-created-and-modified-stored-procedure-with-date-and-time.html).

```
SELECT 
    o.name AS ReferencingObject, 
    sd.referenced_entity_name AS ReferencedObject
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies  AS sd
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
    ON o.object_id = sd.referencing_id
WHERE sd.referenced_entity_name = 'my_object_name';
```

**OR**

```
SELECT  name AS ProcedureName ,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SysObj.modify_date, 103) AS [Create/Modify Date] ,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), CAST(SysObj.modify_date AS TIME), 100) [Create/Modify Time]
FROM    sys.objects SysObj
WHERE   SysObj.type = 'P'
        AND DATEDIFF(D, SysObj.modify_date, GETDATE()) < YEAR(GETDATE())
```

**OR**

```
SELECT  name AS ProcedureName ,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SysObj.modify_date, 103) AS [Create/Modify Date] ,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), CAST(SysObj.modify_date AS TIME), 100) [Create/Modify Time]
FROM    sys.objects SysObj
WHERE   SysObj.type = 'P'
ORDER BY SysObj.modify_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name
FROM sys.procedures
where name like '%someCommonNameOfProcedure%'
```